# SQL group by rows negate by a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `transactions` below:

```
| id | type | transaction |
| 1  | A    | 100         |
| 2  | B    | -500        |
| 3  | A    | 300         |
| 4  | A    | 400         |
| 5  | A    | 500         |
| 6  | B    | -300        |
| 7  | B    | -100        |
| 8  | A    | 100         |
| 9  | B    | -100        |
| 10 | A    | 100         |
| 11 | B    | -100        |
| 12 | A    | 100         |
```

Essentially for each type `A` transaction the `transaction` amount will be positive, and for each type `B` transaction the `transaction` amount will be negative. (B is a reversal transaction of A).

What's the best way to write a sql select statement to filter out all transactions as well as their negated transactions, and only leave the ones that aren't reversed. e.g.

```
| id | type | transaction |
| 4  | A    | 400         |
| 12 | A    | 100         |
```

ps. There won't be any `B` type transactions without `A`.

Comment: the question is how to know which b transaction belongs to which a transaction.

Comment: What if there is an imbalance among transactions that have the same amount.

Comment: Just updated the scenario a little bit. So what actually happens is there could be multiple A/B/A/B/A/B ... transactions but we just need to filter out all of them and leave the ones that aren't negated.

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear, but ideally you need a `reversals` table with just a `transactionID`

Comment: Why isn't `| 5  | A    | 500         |` in the expected output  that one also doesn't look like it's reversed

Comment: @LiamG I agree, but this is the situation for now

Comment: @RaymondNijland id 2

Comment: @raymond-nijland it is : `| 2  | B    | -500        |`

Comment: Still wierd that means the reverse did happen before the transaction assuming the id column is a auto_increment @LiamG

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah it could happen in the medical world (Rx refills)

Comment: @raymond-nijland The tables are weird, if they were not, there would be at least an id saying which `b` trasaction bolongs to which `a` transaction, or a different table.

Comment: @Sirmyself I completely agree, unfortunately I wasn't involved in the table designing. This is the table I'm working with.

Comment: @hankboo I understand your pain, sometimes, we don't have much control over the environment we use, we just have to deal with it.

Comment: the best i can think off will only get type and transaction columns because you don't know which b belonges to which a it's impossible to also get the exact matching id column

Comment: @RaymondNijland Can you paste your solution?

Comment: Don't think i will post that as answer it closly resembles Gordon Linoff answer.. i might have a other idea to try..

Answer (score 1):

If there is a 1-1 correspondence, then `not exists` works pretty well:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where not exists (select 1
                  from transaction t2
                  where t2.type <> t.type and t2.transaction = - t.transaction
                 );
```

This specifically fails when one transaction can have multiple amounts that are the same.  For that, I might recommend aggregation instead:

```
select amount, sum(type = 'A') as num_as, sum(type = 'B') as num_bs
from transactions t
group by abs(amount)
having sum(amount) <> 0;
```

This doesn't return the original rows, but it does show where things don't line up.

Comment: I agree, however the situation is to return the original rows (at least `id`) for further processing..

Comment: @hankboo the first query should do you good unless a transaction may have the same amount. If that is the case, a table redesign would be a better solution.

Comment: @Sirmyself It wouldn't work when there's `A 100`, `B -100`, `A 100`. It would return 0 rows instead of a `A 100`

Comment: @hankboo then your best solution would be to ask for a table redesign whene each `b` transaction is associated with one `a` transaction

Comment: @HankBoo . . . The problem is with duplicate amounts -- how do you know which rows to return?  According to your sample data, you are returning only one "100", but which one?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good question, I should've been more clear in the question. It doesn't matter which row it returns, anyone is fine.